# TeamCity composite build configuration doesn't fail

Tags: teamcity

My composite build configuration **A** depends on snapshot dependency **B**. Also, I adjusted *On failed dependency* with *Make build failed to start value*.

[Snapshot dependency options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8obVs.png)

So I expected that when B is failed then A is failed too. But It doesn't happen and my composite build configuration **A** stay always greed.

What should I check?

UPDATE: This is the problem only with ***composite*** build type. If I create ***regular*** build configuration everything works correctly.

Comment: could you provide us an error message ?

Comment: My snapshot dependency B is a tests runner so it's failed if any test fails.

Comment: The problem was resolved after upgrading TeamCity version to 2018.1.